# How can I filter on date values?

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

Using `RODBC`, I would like to query a table and return everyone who is 80 years old or older.

The query I use (within my R script) is:

```
sqlQuery(con, "SELECT *
              FROM People
              WHERE BirthDT >= '1941-02-11'")
```

The `BirthDT` field looks like this:

```
 [1,] "1937-07-12"
 [2,] "1939-04-20"
 [3,] "1938-11-10"
 [4,] "1987-10-24"
 [5,] "1991-07-04"
 [6,] "1984-03-24"
 [7,] "1986-03-14"
 [8,] "1937-08-18"
 [9,] "1938-09-28"
[10,] "1934-08-23"
```

I have also tried this (different date format specified):

```
sqlQuery(con, "SELECT *
              FROM People
              WHERE BirthDT >= '11/02/1941'")
```

As before, it doesn't filter as expected.

I have tried some variations of this query, including an explicit date cast/conversion, yet nothing seems to work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: since you tagged it as a r question it can be done like this 'ab <- d2[(d2$firstPublicationDate > "2000-01-01"),]
'

Comment: It's an R package and I want to do the date filtering within the SQL query itself before it comes into my environment. `SQL` tag added for clarity.

Comment: this answer might help you bit more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152303/how-do-i-remove-rows-based-on-a-range-of-dates-given-by-values-in-2-columns

Comment: I know the R solution, but that is irrelevant as this query relates to an R package (`RODBC`). Speficially, my question relates to an R package that uses SQL within it.

Comment: what is the class of the date? column

Comment: See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020299/rodbc-date-filter> I think this brings you further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rodbc date filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020299/rodbc-date-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 80 years old or older.

This means that they were born *earlier* than current-date - 80 years.  Your comparison is in the wrong direction:

```
sqlQuery(con, "SELECT *
              FROM People
              WHERE BirthDT <= '1941-02-11'")
```

Comment: It's been a long day... To be honest, I hadn't even suspected that I'd hit the wrong key because some of the earlier returned results occurred before 1941. In fact, why might that have happened considering the `>=` syntax?